# No se reconoce "Data" en el espacio de nombres Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql

estoy intentando probar conexiones con la base de datos en .NET6, según revisé, el paquete System.Data.SqlClient no va más en .NET6, en su lugar, se utiliza Microsoft.Data.SqlClient pero luego de ejecutar

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.1.0
```

Sigo teniendo errores, porque el "Data" no se reconoce en el paquete instalado y el SqlConnection sigue buscando la referencia en el System.Data.SqlClient

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var sql = $"";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(""))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // var asd = connection.Query<ValidateCredentialsOut>(sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano
Saludos!

Comment: Saca el using que no va mas.. si no, trata de buscarlo en los dos lugares...

Comment: al quitarlo igualmente me dice que el tipo "SqlConnection" no se reconoce

Comment: mira.. aca no estas mostrando eso.. mostranos que lo sacaste, y cual es el error cuando lo sacas.. lo sigue buscando ahi?

Answer (score 0):

Esto a mi me paso cuando llegué a usar varias librerías y estas compartían **namespaces** lo que hice fue escribir el namespace completo
Ejemplo:

```
var connection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
```